# Regular Expression extract first three characters from a string

Tags: regex

Using a regular expression how can I extract the first 3 characters from a string (Regardless of characters)? Also using a separate expression I want to extract the last 3 characters from a string, how would I do this? I can't find any examples on the web that work so thanks if you do know.

Comment: The extraction part is language dependent. Matching it is pretty trivial, have a look around at some tutorials and you should be able to get it. (I recommend this one: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) Good luck

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Any programming language should have a better solution than using a regular expression (namely some kind of `substring` function or a `slice` function for strings). However, this can of course be done with regular expressions (in case you want to use it with a tool like a text editor). You can use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to indicate the beginning or end of the string.

```
^.{0,3}
.{0,3}$
```

This matches up to 3 characters of a string (as many as possible). I added the "0 to 3" semantics instead of "exactly 3", so that this would work on shorter strings, too.

Note that `.` generally matches any character **except** linebreaks. There is usually an `s` or `singleline` option that changes this behavior, but an alternative without option-setting is this, (which really matches **any** 3 characters):

```
^[\s\S]{0,3}
[\s\S]{0,3}$
```

But as I said, I strongly recommend against this approach if you want to use this in some code that provides other string manipulation functions. Plus, you should really dig into [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks, I can't use substring, I've inherited a program that allows regex to be used to manipulate fields and I wanted to add in a new regex rather than mess with code. Thanks

Comment: @user1226884 fair enough. in any case, next time you ask a regex question, please include the language or tool you are using. it matters a lot for anything more complex than this ;). and do check out that tutorial. it is definitely worth knowing some regex basics.

Comment: In my case I need to capture the everything from character  position 178 to last but one.Please help what will be the regex

Comment: @MartinEnder, is there a way to say get 3 out of 4 characters from the beginning? I am looking to do something similar, but need the 2nd-4th characters, i.e., lxyz300.domain.com, I would want the XYZ. This helps a great deal to get the first 4 and I can strip the first one off, but it would be nice to get just the 3 that I need. This is for a python-based language.